# Montage-wrapper: How to use montage to produce an all Sky map

Tags: astronomy, astropy, montage

I'm currently attempting to use astropy's montage-wrapper module, and I'm attempting to re-create the ROSAT all-sky Survey image (found at the tope of the page here: [enter link description here](http://www.xray.mpe.mpg.de/rosat/survey/sxrb/12/fits.html))

I have all of the maps listed (I'm ignoring the uncertainty maps for the time being), and have begun to stitch them together using the montage-wrapper. However, what is output is not what I wanted, and this is almost certainly down to my lack of knowing how to use the montage wrapper.

I have the fits files listed, and I'm using:

```
import montage_wrapper as montage
montage.mosaic('X-RAY', 'MOSAIC', background_match=True)
```

I'd of course be delighted if my output fits looked something similar to this:

[image]

Instead, my output fits looks something like this:

[image]

How would I specify the coordinates system for montage to "wrap" too? Are there any pre-made headers that could possible make the projection seen in the top image?

Comment: The montage wrapper is a fairly light wrapper on montage (http://montage.ipac.caltech.edu/).  You might want to ask there, but it would be good to refer them to this SO question (I don't know if any of the developers have SO accounts)

Comment: Maybe check out the reproject package (https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?